# Excel Macro to auto filter and export result

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file having a column C with sometimes repeteated values:

```
 A | B | C 
------------
 1 | 2 | a
 1 | 4 | b
 1 | 5 | c
 1 | 2 | d
 1 | 6 | a
 4 | 2 | d
 1 | 2 | a
 4 | 4 | c
 8 | 2 | c
 1 | 8 | d
```

I would like create a macro that filter C column for each value (a,b,c,d, ..,n) and save the result in a new file.

In my example the macro return 4 file F1, F2, F3, F4 whit this content:

```
 A | B | C 
------------
 1 | 2 | a
 1 | 6 | a
 1 | 2 | a


 A | B | C 
------------
 1 | 4 | b


 A | B | C 
------------
 1 | 5 | c
 4 | 4 | c
 8 | 2 | c


 A | B | C 
------------
 1 | 2 | d
 4 | 2 | d
 1 | 8 | d
```

How could be written the macro?

Comment: Probably by start writing it? Sorry, but you only dropped requirements. The idea here is that you show code, and then people help fixing problems in that code. Otherwise it sounds like you expect other people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. You have to manually save the created files everytime. Let me know if you want me to set a default location and save all files automatically.

\code\

```
Function perform_click()

Dim i, lastrow As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Workbook

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook
lastrow = ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C500000").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & lastrow).Copy Range("P4")
ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P4:P" & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo


ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

For i = 4 To ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P500000").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C" & lastrow).AutoFilter 3, ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & i).Value
Set ws2 = Workbooks.Add
ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws2.SaveAs "C:\Users\Praveen Behera\Desktop\F" & i & ".xlsx", 51
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set ws2 = Nothing
Next i

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

perform_click

End Sub
```

Comment: yes, my target is save all files in my Desktop. Thanks!

Comment: Great thanks. Please mark my response as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use a Oledb query to get the distinct values of column c  into an array...and then write another query to get values for different values of the array.